# read variable value in main from thread in c++

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex

I need to have a thread which executes a function in while loop(say increments an int value). In the main I need to have a while loop which executes some function(say a for loop which counts from 0 to 5) and then reads the current value of a variable in the thread.  The thread must keep running its own while loop irrespective of whats going on in main. However the value of the thread variable must not change while main reads the variable.

I guess this problem can be solved using atomic. However this is a toy problem in which the variable in the thread is an int. In my actual problem the thread variable if of type Eigen::quaternionf or float[4]. So I need to ensure that the entire Eigen::quaternionf or float[4] is held constant when it is read from main.

The cout in the thread is only for debugging. If the code runs with thread safety, it can be removed. I read from another post that using cout in a thread safe manner may need to write a new wrapper around cout with a mutex. I want to avoid it.

My main concern is reading the variable in correct order in main.

My code fails(today is my first day with multithreading) and is as below along with observed output(selected parts). the code fails to keep the order of the output using cout(garbled output). Also I am not sure that the thread variable is correctly read by the main.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

int i = 0;


void safe_increment(std::mutex& i_mutex)
{

    while(1)
    {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(i_mutex);
    ++i;

    std::cout << "thread: "<< std::this_thread::get_id() << ", i=" << i << '\n';
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::mutex i_mutex;  

    std::thread t1(safe_increment, std::ref(i_mutex));


   while(1)
{
    for(int k =0; k < 5; k++)
    {
    std::cout << "main: k =" << k << '\n';
    }

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(i_mutex);
    std::cout << "main: i=" << i << '\n';
}
}
```

The output(selected parts) I get is

```
thread: 139711042705152, i=223893
thread: 139711042705152, i=223894
thread: 139711042705152, i=223895
main: i=223895
main: k =0
thread: main: k =1139711042705152
main: k =2
main: k =3
, i=main: k =4
223896
thread: 139711042705152, i=223897
thread: 139711042705152, i=223898



thread: 139711042705152, i=224801
thread: 139711042705152, i=224802
main: i=224802
main: k =0
main: k =1
thread: main: k =2
main: k =3
main: k =4
139711042705152, i=224803
thread: 139711042705152, i=224804
thread: 139711042705152, i=224805
```

Comment: you need to synchronize when streaming to `std::cout` to fix the garbling.  it is shared between `main` and `t1`.

Comment: can you give any example code? this is my first day with threads

Comment: you could use another mutex for `std::cout` just like the one you already are using. or reuse that mutex for both `i` and `std::cout`...just move the lock up (in `main`) before the for loop. of course that pretty much makes this entirely synchronous, but it is just an example.

Comment: you could use std::atomic for the counter

Answer (score 1):

`i` is properly synchronized with the mutex. well done! obviously this runs until you force it to stop, so when you do find a better way to end execution, be sure to [join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) on your thread.

to fix the garbling, you need to synchronize on `std::cout`:

```
int main()
{
    std::mutex i_mutex;  

    std::thread t1(safe_increment, std::ref(i_mutex));

    while(1)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(i_mutex);//moved up here to sync on std::cout << k
        for(int k =0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            std::cout << "main: k =" << k << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "main: i=" << i << '\n';
        if (i > 100) break;
    }

    t1.join(); //thread will continue and main will wait until it is done
    //your thread needs to have some way out of its while(1) as well.
}
```

the thread can maybe be this:

```
void safe_increment(std::mutex& i_mutex)
{
    while(1)
    {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(i_mutex);
    ++i;

    std::cout << "thread: "<< std::this_thread::get_id() << ", i=" << i << '\n';
    if (i > 111) break;
    }

}
```

Comment: your code works fine. The data is read correctly in main after being incremented in the thread. However the thread seems to be executing in a non uniform way between two iterations in the while loop in main. Sometimes it would increment variable 50 times between two iterations in while loop in main. Sometimes it would not increment even once in 20 iterations in the while loop in main. Is this because the cores are simultaneously executing other jobs?

Comment: something like that, yea. at this point we're at the mercy of the scheduler. I get different output each time I run it. right now it is running for quite some time without `safe_increment` getting a chance to progress....  ahh multithreading :)